# How do I insert a lot of html into a page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a comment script using PHP and jquery.

My jquery post data to my php backend script, on success I need it to insert the results that the backend script sends back.

Right now I have everything working except the part that adds the comment to the page I am stuck.  I can use something like this;

```
$('#comments').prepend(data.comment);
```

The above code will add the text/comment portion into the comments div but I need it to do more then just add the text, I need it to add the other div's, the comment text, the user's photo, date, all the other things you see in the photo below.

I have no problem getting all this data, but how should I go about adding it all to the page?

Something similar to this below but with much, much more code?

```
 $('div#loader').append('<span class="success">Thanks for your comment!</span>');
```

---

Here is the page with the existing comments, when a ajax post is added, I need to insert the new comment into the list and have it look like the others

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/21/4e/f0/1505261/0/800/screenshot2b20.png](http://img2.pict.com/21/4e/f0/1505261/0/800/screenshot2b20.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would absoluteley not recommend that you send HTML-markup in your requests. If you use JSON, for example, you will save bandwidth and your users will be happier with a site that loads up faster.

It's better if you use jQuery and JavaScript to clone a template from your page (can be a hidden div for example):

```
<div class="comment-template">
   <div class="header">{title}</div>
</div>
```

And then in your JS:

```
$.post('action', data, function(data) {
      var template = $('.comment-template');
      var placeholder = $('#somePlaceholder');

      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var comment = template.clone();
         comment.html(comment.html.replace('{title}', data[i].title));
         comment.appendTo(placeholder);
      }
   },
   "json"
);
```

This sure will work alot faster than including the markup in your requests.

Comment: This is what I was hoping, to use some sort of template.  My script is using a json response right now the json returns, comment text, date the users ID number and photo URL are in a PHP session variable so i'm guessing I need to add them to a JS var?  Also your line above that has the replace title part, would I need to do a line like this for each item, name, photo, comment?

Comment: For more advanced templates you could use helper libraries as someone just suggested (http://jtemplates.tpython.com/). Else you would have to replace each value or use another jQuery selector and a placeholder in your template.
The parameter "data" that are used in the callback-function when calling $.post is what will contain your JSON object (that you return from your php-page). With this you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this many ways:

1. You can create a bunch of elements in jQuery via `$('<div/>').html('Hi Mom')` and build up your DOM that way
2. You can build up the HTML you want as part of your ajax return set (wastes bandwidth)
3. You can create a template and change values.

IE:

```
<div id="someTemplate" style="display: hidden">
    <div class="username"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now you can get the contents of someTemplate, duplicate it, fill in the details by classname, and you're good.

Comment: @redsquare, I have had to do something like this myself but have never looked at jTemplates (I haven't looked for anything, actually).  Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating a lot of HTML data then you could have your PHP script return the HTML and then append it using:

```
$.post('/Url/', data, function(html) {
  $('div#loader').append(html);
}, "html");
```

The advantage to this is that it's easy and allows you to reuse the HTML generation on the server. The disadvantage is it uses more bandwidth than a Json implementation.

The alternative would be to have your script return Json and build up your HTML on the client via DOM manipulation.

```
$.post('/Url/', data, function(x) {
  var elm = document.createElement('div');
  elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x.comment);
  $('div#loader').append(elm);
}, "json");
```

This uses less bandwidth than returning HTML but will be more complicated to create/maintain if the HTML changes.

Comment: "disadvantage is it uses more bandwidth"- I think that it's safe to assume that the HTML returned from a comment generation will not be the one that consume most of the bandwidth.. so.. this is another form of premature optimization :)

Comment: @amikazmi True, but it's still a disadvantage when comparing against a Json implementation. I can't speak for the amount of HTML jasondavis will be returning. I've updated my answer to make it a bit clearer.